# armadillo cov function input

Tags: c++, statistics, armadillo

I am trying to generate a covariance matrix of of a random dataset using the armadillo cov() function.But what I don't understand is how exactly does one generate the matrix input out of the random dataset (input to the cov function) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vector to store your random dataset and pass it to the matrix.

http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat